# What is "Verbose" in scikit-learn package of Python?

Tags: svm, python, scikit-learn

What is "Verbose" in `scikit-learn` package of Python? In some models like neural network and svm we can set it's value to true. This is the  documentation:

**verbose : bool, default: False
    Enable verbose output. Note that this setting takes advantage of a per-process runtime setting in libsvm that, if enabled, may not work properly in a multithreaded context.**

What is this option?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As Matthew states it is generally an option for producing detailed logging information. 
You should be aware, and will probably notice if you enable verbose > 0, that printing to the screen is generally a very slow process. The algorithm may run an order of magnitude slower, or more, with verbose enabled. 
Also, in multi-threaded applications, input/output operations are often disabled. Thus as the documentation advises, writing to the standard output may not work in a multi-threaded context.

Answer (score 10):

Verbose is a general programming term for *produce lots of [logging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logfile) output*.  You can think of it as asking the program to "tell me everything about what you are doing all the time".  Just set it to true and see what happens.